# I want a Report based of this 2 tables

Tags: sql, oracle11g

```
   create table label_table(
   label_id number not null,
   label_name varchar2(50),
   no_months number not null,
   no_of_mobile_sims number not null,
   no_of_services number not null,
   delayed number not null,
   value_of_client number(6,2),
   constraint pk PRIMARY KEY(label_id)
   );

   create table client(
   customer_id number not null,
   customer_name varchar2(50) not null,
   no_months number not null,
   no_of_mobile_sims number not null,
   no_of_services number not null,
   delayed number not null,
  value_of_client number(6,2),
  constraint pk_key PRIMARY KEY(customer_id)
  ) ;


  SELECT
   l.label_id,
   l.label_name,
   k.customer_id,
   k.customer_name
   FROM
   label_table   l
   inner JOIN client k ON k.value_of_client>l.value_of_client                                        
   ORDER BY 1;
```

If we do a select * from client we have this output:

```
13 x_name        3                 4              2           0           74.38
```

And if we do a select * from label_table we this output:

```
1 Diamond                  2                 2              2          0              70
2 Gold                     2                 1              2          2              50
```

We have our client x_name who join our phone company let s say and i want to have a report where
it will say that x_name is a diamond client based on a comparison between the common columns of these 2 tables and i want an output like this:

13 x_name Diamond

And i want to this with a join but the problem is every time i try my client will be identified with both labels because he respect the conditions(>,<,!=,=) of both labels.
The idea is i have 16 clients that have different values and i want to put every one of them in a unique label not in more based on this 2 tables.
For example client.no_of_months>label.table.no_of_months,client.value_of_client>label.client.value_of_client then a label but how i said upper i need every client to be in his first choice label if a client is a diamond the output will be diamond not diamond,gold,silver,bronze even if he can be in that labels too.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you may try below query -

```
SELECT customer_id, customer_name, label_name
FROM (SELECT k.customer_id,
             k.customer_name,
             l.label_name,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY k.customer_id ORDER BY l.value_of_client DESC) RN
      FROM label_table   l
      inner JOIN client k ON k.value_of_client>l.value_of_client)
WHERE RN = 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

Comment: it does give an error..from keyword not where it was expected

Comment: @Kawa, Forgot the comma. Try now.

Comment: It does not work the output are just 4 values from 16 and it put a client in two labels in continue

Comment: Isn't it your expected result?

Comment: Do you need only first row?

Comment: I need all my clients to be in output + the label that they should be based on not only that condition i put in my example in a comparison between all the common columns like no_months number not null,
   no_of_mobile_sims number not null,
   no_of_services number not null,
   delayed number not null,
  value_of_client number(6,2), these are in common and need all to be compared to put a client in a label

Comment: You output is not at all clear. Please post your output in tabular format how it should looks after final select.

Comment: https://imgur.com/kXXCAkh  This is an example of a report but made from other tables is very similar

Comment: @Kawa, Can you give it a try now?

Comment: I did it anyway i post the answer up :)

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT
  k.customer_id,
  k.customer_name,
  l.label_name
  FROM
  label_table   l
  right JOIN client k ON k.value_of_client != l.value_of_client
where l.label_id=(case when k.value_of_client>(select value_of_client from label_table where label_id=1)
                   and  k.delayed=(select delayed from label_table where label_id=1)
                   and k.no_months >(select no_months from label_table where label_id=1)
                   and k.no_of_services>=(select no_of_services from label_table where label_id=1)
                   and k.no_of_mobile_sims>=(select no_of_mobile_sims from label_table where label_id=1)
                   then 1

                   when k.value_of_client > (select value_of_client from label_table where label_id=2) 
                   and  k.delayed<(select delayed from label_table where label_id=2)
                   and k.no_months >=(select no_months from label_table where label_id=2)
                   and k.no_of_services>=(select no_of_services from label_table where label_id=2)
                   and k.no_of_mobile_sims>(select no_of_mobile_sims from label_table where label_id=2)
                   then 2

                   when k.value_of_client>(select value_of_client from label_table where label_id=3)
                   and  k.delayed<(select delayed from label_table where label_id=3)
                   and  k.no_months >(select no_months from label_table where label_id=3)
                   and  k.no_of_services>(select no_of_services from label_table where label_id=3)
                   and  k.no_of_mobile_sims>(select no_of_mobile_sims from label_table where label_id=3)
                   then 3
                   else 4
                   end)
ORDER BY 1;
```